# Missing AppSettings.json file data

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, bamboo, iis-8.5

I have a .NET CORE 3.1 ASP.NET MVC solution that I am trying to deploy to a Windows Server 2012 box using Bamboo.  I can compile everything perfectly using Bamboo and the 'dotnet publish' command.  I can deploy my code to a full IIS instance with its own site w/ all the latest updates running Windows Server 2012w / IIS 8.5.  The app pool for the site is set to run unmanaged code.  The site won't load in the browser.  When I run the exe manually for the site in question, it states that it can't find a setting from my appsettings.json file for the project in question.  I opened EVERY SINGLE JSON FILE in the directory for the site.  None of them conatined the string I need.  I double checked on my local machine and everything is there.  What could be the cause of this issue?  What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you use the `dotnet` publish command to publish the asp.net core application, it will publish the application in debug mode. That means it will not contain the automatcaly generated web.config. Without this web.config your IIS will not run your web application in the by using aspnet core module.

To solve this issue, you should publish the application by using the release mode.

Command as below:

```
 dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

The genreated publish folder as below:

[image]